# Using dictionary to count how many times each image was shown(Can someone explain challenge 1 Project12 (HackingWithSwift))

Tags: swift

GitHub link: https://github.com/Cellomaster87/Storm-Viewer-/tree/challenge12-1a.

Above is complete code but i have noticed many of us that have been using this course for learning doesn't really understand what is happening.

Firstly we needed a dictionary to store the times each pictures would have been viewed I created one like this:

```
  var pictDict = [String: Int]()
```

2. Then we modified the cellForRowAt method to include a phrase that would let the user know how many times a picture would have been seen. But in picDict we only have [picture]! why?

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Picture", for: indexPath)
   let picture = pictures[indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel?.text = picture
   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Viewed \(pictDict[picture]!) times."

   return cell
   }
   ```
3. We then added this pictDict[item] = 0 to the loadPictures method to set the viewed times to 0 for every single picture.So Swift knows that 0 should be assigned as a value?

   ```
   @objc func loadPictures() {
      let fm = FileManager.default
      let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
      let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)

      for item in items {
          if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
              pictures.append(item)
              picDict[item] = 0//set the viewed times to 0 for every single picture.
          }
   ```

4.Inside didSelectRowAt we added this after the if let statement. But does it mean that any value of Int type we put inside [] swift knows that it refers to value from its dictionary

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as? DetailViewController{
        
        vc.selectedImage = pictures[indexPath.row]
        vc.selectedPictureNumber = indexPath.row + 1
        vc.totalPictures = pictures.count
       
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
       
    }
    let picture = pictures[indexPath.row]
    picDict[picture]! += 1
    save()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I was using help of Michele Galvagno site :https://artisticscoreengraving.wordpress.com/2019/03/25/hacking-with-swift-challenge-12/ for making this question

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary contains key-value pairs. It's something like a lookup table. The `String` key represents a picture name of the data source array and the `Int` value represents the amount of views.

- 2. `pictDict[picture]!` is the syntax for `key subscription` and means *fetch the value for the current picture*. It must be unwrapped because a dictionary value is being returned as an optional.
- 3. `items` is the array of (file) names. In the loop the dictionary is populated with the names as keys and with zero values.
- 4. In `didSelectRow` the picture name is taken from the data source array by the given index path (`let picture = pictures[indexPath.row]`) and the corresponding value in the dictionary is incremented (`picDict[picture]! += 1`).